# Using ng-repeat on an array within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to iterate through the JSON array and through the ingredients/directions array using ng-repeat. What I have isn't working. Any advice? Thanks!

Controller:

```
recipeControllers.controller('DetailsController', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams',
function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
$http.get('app/data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.recipe = data;
    $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;
    $scope.recipeIngredients = recipe[whichItem].ingredients;
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="recipe">
    <div class="ingredients">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in recipeIngredients">{{recipeIngredients[whichItem].ingredients}}</li>
        </ul>
     </div> 
</div>
```

JSON Data:

```
    [
  {
    "dish":"thai_chicken_satay",
    "ingredients": ["chicken", "sauce", "stuff"],
    "directions": ["step1", "step2", "step3"]
  },

  {
    "dish":"duck_confit",
    "ingredients": ["duck", "confit", "otherstuff"],
    "directions": ["step1", "step2", "step3"]
  }

]
```

Comment: is `itemId` a 0-indexed index of the item you want to show? or is it something else.

Comment: Where is the actual `ng-repeat`?

Comment: I'm a newbie programmer, so please excuse any obvious mistakes.

Comment: don't necessarily need an ng-repeat for this, though it is weird that the question mentions trying to use it but doesn't show it.

Comment: @KevinB, the question is about "trying to iterate ... using ng-repeat"

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong code. I've been trying many different ways of doing this. I put the ng-repeat where I think it should go, but at this point it's guesswork.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assign `$scope.recipeIngredients` properly (i.e. `whichItem` is properly set and maps to an actual object in your JSON data), then `$scope.recipeIngredients` already points to an array of ingredients (e.g. `["duck", "confit", "otherstuff"]`), so to iterate you simply need to do:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in recipeIngredients">{{item}}</li>
```

If you need to iterate over the entire data array of recipes, then a nested `ng-repeat` is needed:

```
<div ng-repeat="recipe in recipes">
  <div>{{recipe.dish}}</div>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in recipe.ingredients">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: whichItem maps to whatever recipe (JSON object) I selected from the previous page, so I'm not sure how to properly assign $scope.recipeIngredients

Comment: You arleady do that with `$scope.recipeIngredients = recipe[whichItem].ingredients;` (actually, it should be `$scope.recipe[whichItem].ingre...` or `data[whichRecipe].ingre...`)

Comment: For instance, if I just use <li>{{recipe[whichItem].ingredients}}</li>, then I'll get back the entire string on one line. I'd like each ingredient on its own line. Thanks so much for your help thus far.

Comment: @breken, and I gave you the answer... your `$scope.recipeIngredients` already points (if you fixed the typo/bug I mentioned) to the ingredients array - so, `ng-repeat` over that

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but it still doesn't seem to be working. I may be misreading your directions, however. Controller:  $scope.recipe = data;
        $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;
        $scope.data[whichItem].ingredients = recipeIngredients;   and in my HTML:    <div ng-repeat="recipe in recipes">
        <div>{{recipe.dish}}</div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in recipe.ingredients">{{item}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

Comment: @breken, what do you ultimately want - a list of recipes, or given a recipe (or `itemId`) display a list of igrendients?

Comment: @breken, following your example, is this what you want? http://plnkr.co/edit/Yx1IOw1C9Adzp1nSbErz?p=preview

Comment: Anyway I can buy you a beer?!